# How do I exclude files in ADF when they don't have a file extension?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Sorry guys if this is the wrong place I couldn't find a separate data wranging stack.

eed to SFTP files generated every 15 minutes up to an external SAAS product.

Problem is the app generating these files has a hard lock on them. It monitors realtime and keeps appending. The target system doesn't actually need those files. But it does need all the other files in the folder.

The files don't have an extension so I can't pattern match the ones to copy up.

Is there anyway to do this in ADF natively?

Or if it can't do that can I run a python script or powershell and pass the file list I want it to send back to ADF?

The files have RTA in the name so I'm sure I can regex that string in python. Its the passing that list back to ADF for the pipeline job is the bit I have no clue.